# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'CityNameHotel_Name'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error when ever i try to bind two database table columns to single dropdown list.

here is code that i used :

```
GetHotelNames.DataSource = bh.GetHotelNamess();
GetHotelNames.DataTextField = "CityName"+"Hotel_Name";
GetHotelNames.DataBind();
```

It works fine if i try to get single column values but when i want to concatenate two columns with DataTextField it shows error.

i have searched this from different stack questions and found only one relevant [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827757/how-to-bind-the-data-from-database-to-the-dropdown) 
but i did not get any success with this.
What should i do if i want to get two database table column values to one single dropdown?

Comment: What is the return type `bh.GetHotelNamess()`?

Comment: How your fetching records the data in your GetHotelNames() function , can you post the code?

Comment: @mshsayem DataSet is return type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't specify multiple columns** in `DataTextField`, instead you can create a new concatenated column in your DataSource based on above two columns and then specify that as the `DataTextField`.

For example if at the backend your query is like:

```
Select CityName, Hotel_Name, otherField
From yourtable
....
```

Then create a new column using concatenation *(if its Sql Server then)*:

```
Select CityName, Hotel_Name, otherField, CityName + HotelName as CombinedColumn
From yourtable
....
```

Then you can specify `CombinedColumn` as the `DataTextField`

Currently you are getting the exception due to string concatenation of `"CityName"+"Hotel_Name"` results in `"CityNameHotel_Name"` , and there is no column in your DataSource with the name `"CityNameHotel_Name"`

**EDIT:**
Based on the comment, you are not concatenating your column in the query it should be like:

```
select 
Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name ,
City.CityName + ',' + Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name as CombinedColumn 
FROM Hotel_Info LEFT OUTER JOIN City ON Hotel_Info.CityID = City.CityID
```

Comment: @aami, look at the code example in the code, You can't specify multiple columns as `DataTextField`.

Comment: you mean to say that i have to change my stored procedure for  this? i did that and make a combined column but it is only showing city names instead of showing city and hotels in drop down.

Comment: @aami, Modify your select query like: `select Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name ,City.CityName + ',' + Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name as CombinedColumn FROM Hotel_Info LEFT OUTER JOIN City ON Hotel_Info.CityID = City.CityID`

Comment: Thank you so much , you are king of this.....it works now.
i was missing " + ',' + " in my procedure query

Answer (score 1):

You need to create these concatenate column in your data source itself, for example if you are getting your data from a store procedure than create a new column by concatenate `CityName`  & `Hotel_Name` and then assign this column to your `DataTextField`

Comment: here is my procedure code
 select Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name ,City.CityName as CombinedColumn
 FROM         Hotel_Info LEFT OUTER JOIN   City ON Hotel_Info.CityID = City.CityID

Comment: Change your query to `select 
 Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name ,
 Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name + '_' + City.CityName as CombinedColumn 
FROM Hotel_Info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN City ON Hotel_Info.CityID = City.CityID` and assign `CombinedColumn` to your `DataSource`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GetHotelNames.Items.Clear();

foreach(DataRow item in bh.GetHotelNamess().Tables[0].Rows)
{
    GetHotelNames.Items.Add(new ListItem(item["CityName"] + " " + item["Hotel_Name"])); 
}
```